# Flutter: Provider was used after being disposed

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am in the final stages of completing a fairly large project and are now facing a new issue with provider. By now I have read through almost all available questions on this topic but am still unable to find a solution.

I have two ChangeNotifier models, namely: **AuthProvider** and **UserProvider**.
The error in question occurs when I try to call "authProvider.logout()" from another pushed route (The Settings Page), which *works as expected but throws an error* that

> the UserProvider was used after being disposed.

The AuthProvider is created above the MaterialApp in the following way:

```
MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthProvider>(
            create: (BuildContext context) => AuthProvider.instance(),
          ),
          ...
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: MainPage(),
        ),
      ),
```

The MainPage uses a switch statement to either display the LoginScreen or HomeScreen based on a value from AuthProvider.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AuthStatus authStatus = context.select<AuthProvider, AuthStatus>(
      (AuthProvider auth) => auth.status,
    );
    switch (authStatus) {
      case AuthStatus.NOT_LOGGED_IN:
        ...
      case AuthStatus.LOGGED_IN:
        return MultiProvider(
                    providers: <SingleChildWidget>[
                      ChangeNotifierProvider<UserModel>(
                        create: (BuildContext context) => UserModel(),
                        lazy: false,
                      ),
                      ...
                    ],
                    child: const HomeScreen(),
                  );
        break;
      default:
        ...
    }
  }
```

The UserProvider is initialised from within MainPage above the HomeScreen.

```
MultiProvider(
  providers: <SingleChildWidget>[
     ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProvider>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => UserProvider(),
        lazy: false,
     ),
     ...
  ],
  child: const HomeScreen(),
);
```

From inside the HomeScreen I push the settings page exposing the existing value of the UserProvider and AuthProvider.

```
final AuthProvider authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);
final UserProvider userModel = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);
```

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  PageTransition<SettingsPage>(
    child: MultiProvider(
      providers: <ChangeNotifierProvider<dynamic>>[
        ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthProvider>.value(
          value: authProvider,
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProvider>.value(
          value: userProvider,
        ),
      ],
      child: SettingsPage(),
      ),
      type: PageTransitionType.leftToRightWithFade,
   ),
);
```

And lastly, I have a simple logoutCallback inside the SettingsPage that alongside other logic changes the value of the auth status, thus, (expected) causing the LoginPage to be shown again.

```
SettingsButton(
 title: 'Logout',
 callback: () {
   Provider.of<AuthProvider>(ctx, listen: false).logoutCallback();
   Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
}),
```

The expected behaviour is that the value of the authStatus is changed in the logoutCallback() and when the SettingsPage is popped the HomeScreen will be replaced by the LoginPage because of the switch statement.
Although this happens, I receive a long error of:
[A UserProvider was used after being exposed][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeyor.png

Any help would be appreciated as I'm no longer sure what could be causing this error.
If I should include more information or specific samples from the code, please let me know.

Comment: Ive seen this kind of problem in a app where the stck wasnt being managed properly. Therefore, the instance of a `Provider` based on the `context` of another screen was stil existing. Once the old screens were removed it fixed the error

Answer (score 0):

In the following code snippet that you provided, it is possible that `logoutcallback()` is an async function and it is taking some time to execute. Even before the execution is completed, the widget is removed from the tree.

```
SettingsButton(
 title: 'Logout',
 callback: () {
   Provider.of<AuthProvider>(ctx, listen: false).logoutCallback();
   Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
}),
```

What you could do is that chain the two methods using `then()` or use `async await`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, the logoutCallback is not a Future.

Comment: Does it call an API? Or deletes tokens from the local memory?

Comment: It calls to the FirebaseAuth sign out (which is a future), but regardless it asserts the auth status value. I am fairly certain it is not the logout functionality that is failing, because it works as expected. But as mentioned by @FloydWatson, it is likely it's due to poor stack management. The UserProvider is being disposed prematurely, causing the error.